# Lasagne mlp target out of bound

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, lasagne

Hi I am trying to modify the mnist example to match it to my dataset. I only try to use the mlp example and it gives a strange error.

Tha dataset is a matrix with 2100 rows and 17 columns, and the output should be one of the 16 possible classes. The error seems happening in the secon phase of the training. The model is build correctly (log info confirmed).

Here is the error log:

> ValueError: y_i value out of bounds
>
> Apply node that caused the error:
>
> CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(Dot22.0, b, targets)
>
> Toposort index: 33
>
> Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), >TensorType(int32, vector)]
>
> Inputs shapes: [(100, 17), (17,), (100,)]
>
> Inputs strides: [(136, 8), (8,), (4,)]
>
> Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']
>
> Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0)], [CrossentropySoftmax1HotWithBiasDx(Assert{msg='`sm` and `dy` do not have the same shape.'}.0, CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1, targets)], []]
>
> HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a >back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by >setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, >Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
>   HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

Here is the code:

```
def build_mlp(input_var=None):
    l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 16),
                                 input_var=input_var)

    # Apply 20% dropout to the input data:
    l_in_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_in, p=0.2)

    # Add a fully-connected layer of 800 units, using the linear rectifier, and
    # initializing weights with Glorot's scheme (which is the default anyway):
    l_hid1 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
        l_in_drop, num_units=10,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
        W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform())

    # We'll now add dropout of 50%:
    l_hid1_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid1, p=0.5)

    # Another 800-unit layer:
    l_hid2 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
        l_hid1_drop, num_units=10,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)

    # 50% dropout again:
    l_hid2_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid2, p=0.5)

    # Finally, we'll add the fully-connected output layer, of 10 softmax units:
    l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
        l_hid2_drop, num_units=17,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)

    # Each layer is linked to its incoming layer(s), so we only need to pass
    # the output layer to give access to a network in Lasagne:
    return l_out

def main(model='mlp', num_epochs=300):
    # Load the dataset
    print("Loading data...")
    X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()

    # Prepare Theano variables for inputs and targets
    input_var = T.matrix('inputs')
    target_var = T.ivector('targets')

    # Create neural network model (depending on first command line parameter)
    print("Building model and compiling functions...")
    if model == 'cnn':
        network = build_cnn(input_var)
    elif model == 'mlp':
        network = build_mlp(input_var)
    elif model == 'lstm':
        network = build_lstm(input_var)
    else:
        print("Unrecognized model type %r." % model)

    # Create a loss expression for training, i.e., a scalar objective we want
    # to minimize (for our multi-class problem, it is the cross-entropy loss):
    prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network)
    loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction, target_var)
    loss = loss.mean()
    # We could add some weight decay as well here, see lasagne.regularization.

    # Create update expressions for training, i.e., how to modify the
    # parameters at each training step. Here, we'll use Stochastic Gradient
    # Descent (SGD) with Nesterov momentum, but Lasagne offers plenty more.
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(network, trainable=True)
    updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(
        loss, params, learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)

    # Create a loss expression for validation/testing. The crucial difference
    # here is that we do a deterministic forward pass through the network,
    # disabling dropout layers.
    test_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network, deterministic=True)
    test_loss = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(test_prediction,
                                                        target_var)
    test_loss = test_loss.mean()
    # As a bonus, also create an expression for the classification accuracy:
    test_acc = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(test_prediction, axis=1), target_var),
                  dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    # Compile a function performing a training step on a mini-batch (by giving
    # the updates dictionary) and returning the corresponding training loss:
    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], loss, updates=updates)

    # Compile a second function computing the validation loss and accuracy:
    val_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var], [test_loss, test_acc])

    # Finally, launch the training loop.
    print("Starting training...")
    # We iterate over epochs:
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # In each epoch, we do a full pass over the training data:
        train_err = 0
        train_batches = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train, 100, shuffle=True):
            inputs, targets = batch
            train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets)
            train_batches += 1

        # And a full pass over the validation data:
        val_err = 0
        val_acc = 0
        val_batches = 0
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_val, y_val, 100, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets = batch
            err, acc = val_fn(inputs, targets)
            val_err += err
            val_acc += acc
            val_batches += 1

        # Then we print the results for this epoch:
        print("Epoch {} of {} took {:.3f}s".format(
        epoch + 1, num_epochs, time.time() - start_time))
        print("  training loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(train_err / train_batches))
        print("  validation loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(val_err / val_batches))
        print("  validation accuracy:\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
        val_acc / val_batches * 100))

    # After training, we compute and print the test error:
    test_err = 0
    test_acc = 0
    test_batches = 0
    for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_test, y_test, 100, shuffle=False):
        inputs, targets = batch
        err, acc = val_fn(inputs, targets)
        test_err += err
        test_acc += acc
        test_batches += 1
    print("Final results:")
    print("  test loss:\t\t\t{:.6f}".format(test_err / test_batches))
    print("  test accuracy:\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
    test_acc / test_batches * 100))
```

Answer (score 3):

I Figured out the problem:
my dataset does not have an output for every target, becouse it is too small! There are 17 target outputs but my dataset has only 16 different outputs, and it is missing examples of the 17th output.

In order to resolve this problem, just change the softmax with rectify,

from this:

```
l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
    l_hid2_drop, num_units=17,
    nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)
```

to this:

```
l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
    l_hid2_drop, num_units=17,
    nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
```

Comment: Did you use label 1 to 16 instead of 0 to 15?